# Book from 60s with dinosaurs, spaceships and big bang

Tags: story-identification

This is a book I read years ago - likely in the late 1960s or early 70s.  It was a hardback, and I think (long time ago) the cover had a T-Rex strapped to the back of a rocketship in space.

I am sure most of the story went over my head at the time, but I think the plot was of aliens that somehow were stranded on earth in the time of the dinosaurs.  T-Rex was vaguely similar to the aliens, so they put them through some forced evolution to make companion/servants. There was plotting by the T-Rex against their creators.

The book ended with the aliens managing (either through time dilation or time travel), to get to a "big crunch" of the universe collapsing into a black hole and a subsequent big bang.  By being around during the big bang they were able to shape the new universe more to their liking, and they ended up back on Earth - and I wasn't sure if "our" earth was the new one universe or the old one.

I think that the author was east European or Russian, but now I don't know why I think that.

Despite reading it as a kid, it was definitely not young adult material, which is why I may have missed whole important elements of the book, but it has always stuck with me.

Comment: This sounds a little like End of an Era by Robert J Sawyer. It has dinosaurs, alien life and time travel but I believe was written in the mid 1990's. Are you sure it is from the 1960's?

Comment: Thanks for the clue, but definitely earlier than the 90s - I remember reading it in my early teens, and I was in my 30s in the 90s.

Answer (score 4):

Try J.O. Jeppson (a pseudonym for Janet Asimov), "[The Second Experiment](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5900174-the-second-experiment)"
I never read this, so don't know for sure if this is your query, but the cover image always stayed in my memory.

[image: Cover of *The Second Experiment*, showing a T-Rex straddling a spaceship]

> THE ROIISS—once the masters of the universe, now evolved to pure thought forms. Engaged in war with Life itself, they had no time for Rya, their single surviving daughter.
>
> She was the last of the dynasty. With her faithful robot Tec, she took the last ship to a star with nine planets, the third of which had life.
>
> Then she decided it was time to find a mate. And that this planet was as likely a spot as any to begin her search....